# Infectious modelling S(t) equation

Tags: mathematical-modeling

Has somebody please explain for me how to derive 2.6 equation?

[image]

Comment: What do you know about integration? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried to separate into $\frac{dS}{S} = R_o dR$, integrate both sides we have $lnS = \int R_odR$. What to next since to convert $R_o$ to R? and t parameter?

Comment: It depends, is $R_0$ a function of $R$ or is it a constant? Well, I know what it is according to the solution given but do you?

Answer (score 2):

You might be confused because $S$ and $R$ are functions of $t$, but the derivative is with respect to $R$.  You're correct (except for dropping the minus sign)  at $\ln S = \int -R_0 \; dR.$  But $R_0$ is a constant, so the integral is easy: $\ln S = -R R_0 +C$.  Exponentiate to get

$$S = e^{-RR_0+C} = Ae^{-RR_0}.$$

We've done this without thinking about $t$, but we can put it in now:

$$S(t) =  Ae^{R(t)R_0}.$$

Since I don't have the text, I have to assume that $R(0)=0$.  That is probably evident from the type of problem.  So plug in $t=0$ and we get

$$S(0) = A e^0 = A$$.  Plug that in for $A$ above and you get your equation.

Answer (score 2):

You're already in the right direction. Using separation of variables:
$$ \frac{dS}{dR} = -\frac{\beta S}{\gamma} \implies \frac{1}{S}dS = -\frac{\beta}{\gamma}dR$$
Integrate both sides:

$$ \ln S(t) = -\frac{\beta R(t)}{\gamma} + C  $$ where $C$ is a constant
$$ S(t) = e^c \cdot e^{-\frac{\beta}{\gamma}R(t)}$$

Note that $R_0 = \frac{\beta}{\gamma}$ and $e^c$ will be your $S(0)$